# google docs viewer forcing a user

Tags: php, html, drive

Im trying to get use google doc viewer, but i need it for every client (company) to have there own google drive.

Now the problem that i am facing, is that a user can be logged in with there own google account meaning they will store a file in there Google Drive instead of the company google Drive.

My Question is: Can i force a username to login to and if so how? If not, what is the other way to approach this?

Code so far for testing :

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=www.ezconf.net/docs/SOLI%202008/sample.doc&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```